# Get Sub-string from String with specific Pattern in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following input:

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|49=FIRST|8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|56=MIDDLE|10=245|8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|49=LAST|56=HEMADTS|10=024|
```

Now I want the strings that are starting with "8=???" and end with "10=???|". You can see above that there are exactly two strings that start with 8 and end with 10. I have written a program for this.

Below is my code:

```
public class Main {
  static Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(8=\\w\\w\\w)[\\s\\S]*?(10=\\w\\w\\w)");

  public static void main(String[] args) {     
       String str = "8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|49=FIRST|8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|56=MIDDLE|10=245|8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|49=LAST|56=HEMADTS|10=024|";
       match(str);
  }

  public static void match(String message) { //send to OMS

        Matcher m = r.matcher(message);
        while (m.find()) {
              System.out.println(m.group());
        }
   }
}
```

When I just run this I am getting the wrong output like:

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=849=FIRST`|8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|56=MIDDLE|10=245|`
8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=849=LAST|56=HEMADTS|10=024|
```

You can see the first string in the output. It consists of "8=???" two times but the exact output needs to be like:

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|56=MIDDLE|10=245|
8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=849=LAST|56=HEMADTS|10=024|
```

I also want the un-matched strings in separate as there is a further work with those strings. How can I get that? So, the total output needs to be like:

```
Matched : 8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|56=MIDDLE|10=245|
Matched : 8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=849=LAST|56=HEMADTS|10=024|
UnMatched : 8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=849=FIRST`|
```

Comment: I don't understand why the two currently matching strings don't meet your expectation.

Comment: Take the two currently matching strings. The first string has TWO "8=???" but the exact match is only ONE "8=???" to "10=???"

Comment: I see at least 4 strings that start with `8=` and end with `10=` in your input example.

Comment: Sorry, there are only two strings that exactly start with "8=FIX.4.2" and end with "10=XXX".

Comment: `8=FIX.4.2` appears 3 times, `10=` appears twice. Do you mean a match that does not include another `8=FIX.4.2`?

Comment: @hemachandra Check http://ideone.com/TBPWZl

Comment: @Nick absolutely yes. The one that doesn't match should be in Uumatched string and the remaining two strings are in Matched strings.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew - Thank you Wiktor. It solved my problem, one thing, in the output I need to get ' | ' after 10=XXX. Like 10=245| . What change needs to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a tempered greedy token to match the shortest window possible between 2 strings. That will solve the first problem. To get unmatched strings, just split the string with the pattern.

Use

```
\b8=\w{3}(?:(?!8=\w{3})[\s\S])*?10=\w{3}\|
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NVkRc2/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `8=` - a literal substring
- `\w{3}` - 3 word chars
- `(?:(?!8=\w{3})[\s\S])*?` - a tempered greedy token matching any char (`[\s\S]`), zero or more times, as few as possible, that do not start a `8=` and 3 word chars pattern
- `10=` - a literal substring
- `\w{3}` - 3 word chars
- `\|` - a literal `|`.

Java code:

```
public static Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\b8=\\w{3}(?:(?!8=\\w{3})[\\s\\S])*?10=\\w{3}\\|");
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
   String str = "8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|49=FIRST|8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|56=MIDDLE|10=245|8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|49=LAST|56=HEMADTS|10=024|";
   match(str);
}
public static void match(String message) { //send to OMS
    Matcher m = r.matcher(message);
    System.out.println("MATCHED:");
    while (m.find()) {
       System.out.println(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println("UNMATCHED:");
    String[] unm = r.split(message);
    for (String s: unm) {
        System.out.println(s);  
    }
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/TBPWZl).

Results:

```
MATCHED:
8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|56=MIDDLE|10=245|
8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|49=LAST|56=HEMADTS|10=024|
UNMATCHED:
8=FIX.4.2|9=00394|35=8|49=FIRST|
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood the input string and/or spent no time actually testing in Java.  +1 in any case.